# Function problems including bijective functions

Tags: real-analysis, functions

> Let $f,g: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ such that $$f\left(g(x)\right)=g\left(f(x)\right)\tag{1}$$ for every $x \in \Bbb R$. Show that, if $h: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$, with $h(x)=f(x)-x$ is a bijective function, then there exists $x_0 \in \Bbb R$ so that $g(x_0)=x_0$.

I noticed that there exists $x_0 \in \Bbb R$ so as $f(x_0)=x_0$. Then I got stuck.

Comment: Can you show that $x_0$ is also unique?

Comment: Yes, I can. There exists only one $x_0$ so as $h(x_0)=0$.

Comment: Then you are done...

Answer (score 2):

Since you can show that $f$ has a unique fixed point, you are done. The system \begin{cases}f(g(x_0))\overset{(1)}=g(f(x_0))=g(x_0)\\f(x_0)=x_0\end{cases} implies that both $x_0$ and $g(x_0)$ are fixed points of $f$. Uniqueness implies that they must be equal.

Comment: Now I get it. Very interesting. Thank you so much!